Failing to clip and then export chirps rainfall data as CSV in Google Earth Engine
I wish to export daily rainfal data as CSV in Google Earth Engine for a 40 year period and then export the result as csv. However the code first fails to clip the data to the study area, and also it fails to export the results as CSV. I am getting the error message that Line 16: precipitation.clip is not a function. The code is as follows :
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amazhindu/zimbabwe')
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe)
print(zimbabwe)
print()
Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 6);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1983-01-01', '2023-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe)
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation');
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 17,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.addLayer(precipitation.clip(zimbabwe), precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
var final = precipitation.clip(zimbabwe)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: precipitation,
  description: 'Zimbabwe_Chirps',
  scale: 30,
  region: zimbabwe,
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});


clip is giving you an error, because you are trying to clip a complete ImageCollection, instead of a single image. Furthermore, you do not need a clip, since you need to sample the region of interest with reduceRegion, instead. Then, you need to map the reduceRegion to every image in the image collection and return a Feature with the precipitation data and the date. Finally, you need to export the FeatureCollection with Export.table.toDrive.
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amazhindu/zimbabwe')
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe)
print(zimbabwe)

Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 6);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe)
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation');
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 17,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
var final = precipitation.map(function(image){
  var prec = image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  geometry: zimbabwe.geometry(),
                  scale: 5500,
                  maxPixels: 1e12
                });
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return ee.Feature(null, prec).set('date', date);
});

print('final',final);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(final),
  description: 'Zimbabwe_Chirps',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});


This works fine. Thank you so much for the quick assistance.
